# GPS position within search zone on globe?

Tags: gps, coordinates, globe

How to check if some ocean drifters traveled through MH370 search zone which can be defined by 4 points on globe. I need mathematical equation to calculate if the GPS position of some ocean drifters is within the search zone.

[image: Map of search operations for the underwater search which began in October 2014.]

Comment: Can you clarify "ocean drifters"? Do you have coordinates for the drifters? Do you have access to GIS software? If you don't have the polygons of the search areas, you can digitize them (using more than just 4 points), then use intersect or point-in-polygon.

Comment: Do you want to use a spatial database? What precision do you want to?

Comment: there is the equation: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190117

Comment: @mkennedy More about [ocean drifters](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/phod/dac/index.php) (see "Download all data"; I use buoydata_15001_jun16.dat). Presentation by means of KML file on Google Earth.
I think I just need a basic precision.
Thank you for the equations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Python, although it isn't using proper geographic functions:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

polygon = Polygon([(1, 15), (10, 30), (15, 20), (5, 0), (1, 15)])

points = [
    Point((5, 17)),
    Point((1, 20)),
    Point((15, 30)),
    Point((9, 10))
]

x, y = polygon.exterior.xy

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5), dpi=90)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
for point in points:
    if polygon.contains(point):
        ax.plot([point.x], [point.y], 'go')
    else:
        ax.plot([point.x], [point.y], 'ro')
ax.set_title('Polygon')
plt.show()
```